# Is std::unique_ptr memory aligned?

Tags: c++

Edit: **No It is Not memory aligned. read more for details.**

I have come across the following code:

```
byte* start = xyz;
...
std::unique_ptr<byte[]> aligned_buffer;
aligned_buffer.reset(new byte[10]);
start = aligned_buffer.get();
...
```

It seems like the above creates a new array which is `aligned?` (then we use memcpy to populate its content).
How does this work? Is it 4 byte aligned or 8 byte aligned? How does std::unique_ptr make this happen?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` just manages the lifetime of the associated pointer.  It neither knows nor cares how the pointer itself is aligned - in your case  that is down to `operator new`, so using `aligned_buffer` as the name of the `unique_ptr` is somewhat misleading here.

Comment: @PaulSanders To be fair, when you create a `std::unique_ptr<Car> carPtr`, the `unique_ptr` doesn't know about Cars either but it's still a reasonable variable name, because it describes the thing being pointed to. Otherwise all our pointers would have generic, useless names, like "pointer". The real naming problem here is that the thing being pointed to is [probably] _not_ properly aligned [for the thing that'll end up living there].

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr` doesn't allocate anything so no, it doesn't create aligned storage.  `new` on the other hand does allocate memory and aligns it for the type that it is allocating.  In this case `byte` has an alignment of `1` so that is the alignment the pointer you get from `get` has.

If you want aligned storage you need to allocate something that has the proper alignment like [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) or just allocate the type that you want to create.

Comment: So then the buffer is not aligned at all? (1 byte alignment doesn't mean anything)

Comment: @Nic Correct.  Any address is valid for a `byte` so there is a very good chance it won't be suitably aligned.

Comment: 1-byte alignment means that you are guaranteed not to get fractional pointers (e.g. you don't have to worry about supporting a pointer to the third bit in a byte ;))

Comment: Suggest a big, bold, "it doesn't!" at the top of this answer :P